# Connecting to a nodejs server via android and getting a timeout exception

Tags: java, android, performance, node.js, sockets

Hello i am trying to connect to a nodejs server via java.net socket on android app.
I am managing to get a connection via telNet.
But when trying to open a socket via java i get a timeout exception.

Here is my nodejs code

Server.js :

```
    var userRegisterer = require('./userUtils/uesrRegisterer.js').get;
var net = require('net');


var server = net.createServer(function (connection)
{
    initializeServerDefaults(connection);
    userRegisterer.registerUser(connection, startGame);

    // Will most probly be moved to a diffrent file.
    connection.on('data', recivedData);
});

function startGame()
{

}

server.listen(6000, function ()
{
    console.log('Tank war server started listening on port 4001');
});


function recivedData(data)
{
    // TxO BE ADDED
}

function initializeServerDefaults(conn)
{
    conn.setEncoding('utf8');
}
```

My Java code on andriod :

```
class TcpSocketFactory
{
    public Optional<Socket> createFrom(String ip, int port)
    {
        try
        {
            InetAddress adr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);

            return Optional.of(new Socket(adr, port)); // timeout
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return Optional.absent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm the port you're trying to connect to? The `console.log` says 4001 yet the function `server.listen` is listening in on port 6000. So in java, what port are you passing to `createForm`?

Comment: The port is fine its just and old comment, i tried changing the port to fix the problom to no avail